# compiling my project with boost::regex linked as static

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I am using Boost.Regex in my VC2011 project and the latest Boost.Regex was compiled to a static and dynamic library.

I've forced my VC project to link the static library (boost_regex-vc110-mt-1_49.lib), but after the project was compiled and when it is run, it reports that:

> missing boost_regex-vc110-mt-1_49.dll

I googled the similar problem and someone suggests to use `/D "BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB"`, I tried this, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you perform a complete rebuild (clean and then build)?

Comment: yes, I did. But it doesn't help the program. But I notice one thing, since I use the boost::random too, once I link manually the static lib (boost_random-vc110-mt-1_49.lib) into the project, it doesn't ask me for the dll while running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` then you'll have to specify all your Boost dependencies manually. So, if you want *everything* to be linked statically, then define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and link everything manually. Otherwise, if it's just threads, use `BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB` and simply link `Boost.Regex` manually.